# Is there a large undersea caldera in the Azores?

Tags: geology, volcanology, impacts, sea-floor

There looks like a large undersea circular feature ([Google maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@37.3118628,-25.0687081,333063m/data=!3m1!1e3)) about 120km across with its north edge on Sao Miguel Island and its south edge on Santa Maria Island.

Has any work been done to say whether or not it's a real feature, and if so what it is? When I tried to find out about caldera around the Azores I only found stuff about the smaller caldera on the islands.

Cheers